# how to correlate 2 variables when X > 1

Tags: r, correlation

I have a data set and want to run a correlation between `X` and `Y`. However, I only want to look at `X` values that are greater than 1.

```
cor(Data$X, Data$Y, use = "complete.obs")
```

What argument do I add to run a correlation between `X` and `Y` only for the `X` values that are greater than 1?

Comment: or `with(subset(Data,X>1), cor(X,Y), use="complete.obs")`

Comment: @BenBolker, I received an output of [NA]. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you use @MDK's answer (which should be equivalent to my suggestion, I think ...) ?  If so, we'll probably need a [mcve] ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset using the `[` operator.

Try this:

```
# Generate Example Data
Data <- data.frame(X = seq(-5, 10, 1),
                   Y = sample(1:100, 16))

with(data = Data[Data$X > 1, ], cor(X, Y, use = "complete.obs"))
```

`[` lets us specify rows and columns in the style `my.data.frame[rows, columns]`. Here we are specifying that we want only rows where `X > 1`, but all columns. We could also do the following to ask for each column individually by name:

```
cor(Data[Data$X > 1, "X"], Data[Data$X > 1, "Y"], use = "complete.obs"))
```

Or even the following to subset the column vectors:

```
cor(Data$X[Data$X > 1], Data$Y[Data$X > 1], use = "complete.obs"))
```

Of course, these are only to illustrate the flexibility. It's best to subset the whole data set once to avoid discrepancies.